# C# WPF DataGrid - DateTime formatting

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, datagrid, format

I'm using a `DataTable` (created in code), and I display it's `DefaultView` using a `DataGrid`. The `DataTable` contains a `DataColumn` that has `DateTime` as it's `DataType`.

The `DataGrid` displays dates as: `10/9/2017 12:00:00 AM`. Is there a way to display the `DateTime` values as `10/9/2017` without changing the column's `DataType` to `string`?

Answer (score 4):

Your Binding should look like this

```
{Binding Property, StringFormat=d}"
```

**Full example**

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Your Header" Binding="{Binding Property, StringFormat=d}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: The DataGrid in xaml contains no column definitions, it's just bound to the DataTable's default view. Works perfectly, except for the date display.

Comment: lets c.  gimme some time

Answer (score 2):

You could handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event for the `DataGrid`:

```
private void dg_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
    {
        e.Column = new DataGridTextColumn()
        {
            Binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName) { StringFormat = "d" }
        };
    }
}
```